# If I buy all DLC will the golden menu item "Downloadable Content" disappear?

Tags: rocket-league

I was wondering if I can have "clean" menu if I own all of the Rocket-League's DLC.

Currently in the menu there are 4 items:

- Chaos Run
- Back to the Future™
- Revenge of the Battle-Cars
- Supersonic Fury

On Steam there is also Official Game Soundtrack.

I currently own only Back to the Future™ and in the menu it shows "Already Owned".

Anybody who has all of these 4 DLC, is the menu item still golden?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you have purchased all of the in-game DLC, the Downloadable Content menu disappears. I have purchased all but the soundtrack and the image below is my menu (note no gold DLC option):

[image: In-game menu (no DLC)]

Answer (score 0):

Based on my previous experience, owning Supersonic Fury, Revenge of the Battle-Cars, and the Back to the Future DLC when that was 100% of the available DLC, no, it is still highlighted/visible.

However, I cannot confirm this with all of the current DLC.